# What is the best template place in PHPLucidFrame to add IE conditional statements?

Tags: php, html, css, internet-explorer, phplucidframe

I'm wondering the best template place in [PHPLucidFrame](http://www.phplucidframe.com) to add IE conditional statements for IE-specific styles. I know I can add them in each index.php, but it will be redundant. Is there any suggestion?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to add them explicitly as PHPLucidFrame automatically adds two CSS classes for IE to `<html>` tag such as `ie ieX` where `X` is the current IE version you are viewing with. So, you could just use those classes in your CSS file.

```
.ie { /* for all IE */
}

.ie7 { /* for IE7 */
}

.ie8 { /* for IE8 */
}

.ie9{ /* for IE9 */
}
```

If you don't want to follow that way, the best template to use is `/inc/tpl/head.php`. Copy it into `/app/inc/tpl/` and update `/app/inc/tpl/head.php` with your IE conditional statements. It is automatically available in all pages